# Requested access to the resource is denied during Docker Push in gitlab

Tags: gitlab

Successfully logged in Docker registery.gitlab.com
Bulid the docker image also after buliding unable to push to registery.gitlab.com getting below error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zed9W.jpg)

I have provided all the permission to access token
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFYBL.jpg)
Can you please help me for this issue

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) for why posting images is a bad idea. Your question is generally not clear: please add information on what you are looking to achieve and what you've already tried.